# docker stats: block i/o incorrect for node.js app

Tags: node.js, docker

NodeJS app inside a docker container.

The app only writes periodically some data to a file on a volume mounted to the container (defined in my `docker-compose.yml`)

I try to use `fs.writeSync` and `fs.writeFileSync`
Both ways results with correct data in the file. However, if I use the second way, docker stats have incorrect (zero) data for output (Block IO) for the container. Why?

1)

```js
const fs = require('fs')
setInterval(() => fs.writeFileSync('/data/file.txt', (new Array(1024)).join('.')), 100)
```

2)

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const fd = fs.openSync(`/data/file.txt`, 'w')
setInterval(() => fs.writeSync(fd, (new Array(1024)).join('.')), 100)
```

Comment: Please share more information about the error you're seeing in docker.

Comment: I donn't see any error. In both cases everything is OK. The app works fine. Data (1000 points) in file. But when I start `docker stats` I see different Block IO in this cases. In first case 'output' grows as it should. But in second case it does not.

Comment: Anyway, here is an example: https://github.com/kityan/example-docker-stats
`docker stats` for app2 show zeros. May be it's not `docker stats` issue... May be app2 writes not in block mode?